# Anyone know how to capitalize a page title?

Tags: segments, css, title

I'm using the {segment_2} variable to complete various bits of info on a page. The segment is all lowercase, but that's fine as I'm using CSS to capitalize those elements.

The problem comes when I'd like to use that {segment_2} in the page title. It's appearing all in lowercase and I can't figure out how to make it appear in sentence case.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: Is segment_2 a category?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the [**Streeng plugin**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/streeng).

> Perform common operations on strings. Change case, truncate,
>   find/replace, repeat, encode/decode, generate slugs and more.

One of the parameter options is `capitalize="yes"` which lets you capitalize the first character of the string.

Comment: Please select my answer as correct if this worked for you

Answer (score 6):

[**CE String**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-string) is another great option.

> CE String is a string manipulation tool for use in your ExpressionEngine templates. It is feature-packed, and allows you to manipulate strings (text) with very simple syntax.

You would just do:

```
{exp:ce_str:ing strtoupper}{segment_2}{/exp:ce_str:ing}
```

CE String has *tons* of other useful methods. And the [chaining feature](http://www.causingeffect.com/software/expressionengine/ce-string/user-guide/basics#chaining) that lets you use more than one method can come in handy.